# Backing field and JITer

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, jit

I saw a [pull request](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/pull/630) in ASP.NET repository in Github which is awesome update for ASP.NET, but then I saw this comment

[image]

And now I am intrigued, what does the author meant by

> So JIT can do it's JITty stuff

How is backing field related to JIT optimizations?

Comment: The owner basically meant "why did you not make the property as efficient as it could be?".  The submitter answered "I don't really understand what you mean, but the jitter makes the difference disappear so it doesn't matter".  Which is not correct, he doesn't understand that this property does not require a backing field and with this syntax does generate one, as well as a constructor to initialize it.  Perhaps not realizing that it won't have a setter either way.  Syntax sugar does tend to cause tooth decay.

Comment: @HansPassant, but I don't understand how owner suggestion is better than contributor's code.Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Just try it yourself.  Use ildasm.exe to look at the generated code, you can easily see the difference.

Comment: How can I see eventual JIT optimizations?

Comment: You have to look at the machine code with Debug > Windows > Disassembly. It will inline the property getter (assuming it is not virtual) but not suppress the memory read. The owner's preferred syntax will result in a single MOV instruction that loads a constant.  Or disappear completely if it is, say, used in an if-statement.